# URL Rewrite on IIS: HTTP to HTTPS rule to also include non-www to www redirect

Tags: asp.net, iis, https, url-rewriting

How would I modify this rule to include non-www to www redirect?

```
    <rule name="Force Https" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="healthcheck.html" negate="true" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO}" pattern="https" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

Is there a better way to force HTTPS sitewide? I am using ASP.NET MVC 5 on IIS 8.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to add another rule where it checks if the `HTTP_HOST` variable just contains your host without the `www.` prefix, and redirect if so:

```
<!-- You first rule. Note stopProcessing is now false. -->
<rule name="Force Https" stopProcessing="false">
  <match url="healthcheck.html" negate="true" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO}" pattern="https" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>

<!-- Additional rule. -->
<rule name="Force WWW" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="healthcheck.html" negate="true" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^yourdomain\.com"/>
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="https://www.{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" />
</rule>
```

Just change `yourdomain.com` above to your actual host domain name.

To answer your other question, I think URL redirect (through URL Rewrite) is the simplest way to force HTTPS without returning a 403 to your users who still try to access your site via HTTP.

**UPDATE**

In response to your comment regarding the double 301, you could try this single rule. I do not have my laptop at home to verify, but I think this will work:

```
<!-- This rule will capture any http request regardless of the 'www.' prefix in the URL -->
<rule name="Force Https" stopProcessing="true"> 
  <match url="healthcheck.html" negate="true" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO}" pattern="^http$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.yourdomain.com{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
<!-- This rule will capture https request that does not have the 'www.' prefix in the URL -->
<rule name="Force WWW Prefix" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="healthcheck.html" negate="true" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
    <add input="{HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO}" pattern="https" />
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^yourdomain\.com$"/>
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.yourdomain.com{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Comment: This way works, however it gives two 301 redirects when navigating to http://, I would rather have only one

Comment: getting redirect loop

Comment: @N0ir, oops sorry, your comment makes sense. Try my update to my update. :)

Comment: @N0ir, please change the `HTTP_HOST` pattern to `^yourdomain\.com$`, and the `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO` on the first rule to `^http$` (as per my update).

Comment: when you are experimenting with 301 loops use incognito mode in Chrome, otherwise you need to keep clearing your browser history because the 301 is cached.

Comment: Couple of things (for future readers) : 
1. With 'Redirect' actions, 'stopProcessing' is essentially ignored, since the request is immediately redirected.
2. If you switch the two rules in the first example, there is no double 301 since the (now) first one redirects to HTTPS while removing the 'www'.